# Cargo ship appears in mountains (sci-fi/thriller)

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a long shot but Google and the library catalog have failed me. I did not personally read it and am working off of a friend's description.

This would be a novel, read somewhere between late 90s and 2010s. Premise is, a cargo/container ship appeared in the mountains with no explanation. People go to explore the ship and find that the faces of the crew have become one with the walls and are talking/projecting their voices somehow.

It might be something in teen/YA. Friend read it in middle school/high school, but cannot remember the ending nor which section it was pulled from. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *The Philadelphia Experiment*, which did have a [literary adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Montauk_Project:_Experiments_in_Time) albeit one that doesn't quite match up.

Comment: Which mountains? Alps, Andes, Appalachians?